# How to show that there are $1121505$ conjugacy classes in $S_{61}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

> How to show that there are $1121505$ conjugacy classes in $S_{61}$?

Can someone help me with this question. I have no idea how to count them.

Second Question:
When is a conjugacy class a subgroup?

Comment: Hint: Conjugacy classes in $S_n$ have the same "shape". That means if you express a permutation $\sigma$ into disjoint cycles then the # of cycles will be equal, and the size of each disjoint cycle would be the same. For example, $(1,2,3)(4,5)$ and $(6,7,8)(4,9)$ have the same "shape".

Comment: Yes, so $S_{4}$ has for example 5 conjugacy classes, $S_{5}$ has 7, but how to find a formula for it?

Comment: So the realization is that we are counting the "partitions" of an integer. The partitions of 5 are: 5, 1+4, 2+3,1+2+2,1+1+1+2,1+1+1+1+1,3+1+1.

Comment: The number that you mention is actually the number of conjugacy classes in the symmetric group $S_{61}$. Not $S_{63}$.

Comment: Yes indeed, I changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show that $p(61)=1121505$ where $p(n)$ is the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function), OEIS [sequence A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041), tabulated [here](https://oeis.org/A000041/b000041.txt). You can calculate the values recursively using Euler's recurrence: $p(n)=0$ for $n\lt0;\ $ $p(0)=1;$ and, for $n\gt0,$ 
$$p(n)=p(n-1)+p(n-2)-p(n-2-3)-p(n-3-4)+p(n-3-4-5)+p(n-4-5-6)-p(n-4-5-6-7)-p(n-5-6-7-8)+\cdots$$$$=p(n-1)+p(n-2)-p(n-5)-p(n-7)+p(n-12)+p(n-15)-p(n-22)-p(n-26)+\cdots$$

So $p(1)=p(0)=1,$
$p(2)=p(1)+p(0)=1+1=2,$
$p(3)=p(2)+p(1)=2+1=3,$
$p(4)=p(3)+p(2)=3+2=5,$
$p(5)=p(4)-p(3)-p(0)=5+3-1=7,$
$p(6)=p(5)+p(4)-p(1)=7+5-1=11,$
$p(7)=p(6)+p(5)-p(2)-p(0)=11+7-2-1=15,$
$p(8)=p(7)+p(6)-p(3)-p(1)=15+11-3-1=22,$
$p(9)=p(8)+p(7)-p(4)-p(2)=22+15-5-2=30,$
$p(10)=p(9)+p(8)-p(5)-p(3)=30+22-7-3=42,$
$p(11)=p(10)+p(9)-p(6)-p(4)=42+30-11-5=56,$
$p(12)=p(11)+p(10)-p(7)-p(5)+p(0)=56+42-15-7+1=77,$
$p(13)=p(12)+p(11)-p(8)-p(6)+p(1)=77+56-22-11+1=101,$
etc.